# Define functions for multiple shells

Tags: command-line, bash, zsh, fish

I'm currently using fish shell. As I use frequently `fish`, `zsh`, `bash`, how could I define a function in one of them which will be available for all shell? Do I have to define them in `.profile`?

[image]

Once I leave the terminal and reuse it after, I got :

[image]

Comment: why don't just just define it in a file in your home directory and have the `.*rc` for each shell source the file?

Comment: @Zanna I don't know this technic. Could you respond that as a full answer in using an example?

Comment: OK, doing so...

Comment: This will quickly break for anything but trivial functions. fish has very different syntax.

Comment: The themes is very interactive, but syntax very different. This is one of the primary reasons why I changed to `zsh`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just define the function in the `~/.*rc` file of each of the shells you use. Or you could make a new file for that function and other shell functions that you want to use in all shells... for example...

```
nano shell-functions
```

I define my function inside the file...

```
hi() { echo "How are you $1?" ; }
```

save and exit, then I edit my `~/.bashrc` and `~/.zshrc` and at the end of each of them add the line:

```
source shell-functions
```

or just

```
. shell-functions
```

Which does the same thing.

After editing my `~/.*rc` files, I open a new shell and the function is available:

```
$ bash
$ hi zanna
how are you zanna ?
$ zsh
% hi zanna
how are you zanna ?
```

---

The `source` command reads files and executes commands from them *in the current shell* (unlike when you run a script like `./script` which executes the script in a new shell). In this case, you want to define a function for the shell being opened so you want to `source` the file that contains it to make it available in the shell. If you look in your `~/.profile` you can see an example of one configuration file sourcing another like this:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
```

So the default `~/.profile` sources `~/.bashrc` in Ubuntu. You can also test out `source` by making a file, let's call it `file1`, with some command in it like (for bash) `PS1='I messed up my prompt '` save, exit, then in the shell type `source file1` and you will see the effect (open a new shell (for example type `bash` or open a new terminal window) and everything will be back to normal)...

Comment: I know we could insert alias and functions in `.bashrc` and  `.zshrc`, but how about  a file? This is the only ambiguous thing in your answer. Could you explain a bit more please?

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity I edited to explain the `source` command - is that more clear for you?

Comment: Thanks @Zanna, your answer is well understandable for me!

Comment: @SpinningAtInfinity that is great to hear :)

Comment: Nice, it works well.

Comment: This procedure works well, but the only problem I got is when I leave the terminal, all sets disappear. What could I do for that?

Comment: What do you mean, when you leave the terminal? This way should always work when is it not working?

Comment: Now, you could see I think.  My file `Functions_Alias_Cmd/Execute.sh` is no longer recorded in `~/zshrc` when I leave the terminal.

Comment: You put the `source` command in `~/.zshrc` and saved changes in the file? If you want you could upload your `~/.*rc` files to http://paste.ubuntu.com